# jQuery UI .sortable() with jQuery 1.2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm in need of implementing functionality equal to that of jQuery UI's Sortable method:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

However, I'm not able to use a version of jQuery 1.3+. There is another functionality on the pages that are dependent on the older version which ceases to work when upgrading the older version of jQuery.

I need to implement this either using raw JS or an older version of jQuery. Is there a jQuery plugin or something of the like that is available to facilitate?

Answer (score 0):

What are the other functionalities that cease to work?
Cause I had some issues as well by upgrading to 1.3.2 earlier this week, but it came down to a certain syntax change from 1.2 to 1.3. So it was easily fixed.

For you it might of course be very much different...